# How to add icons to a combobox left side

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I've been at this for days now and can't seem to find anything helpful online like sample code for a combo box written in visual C++ and not in C#. I've tried sample code for a CTreeCtrl and images and it works. But I'm having issues with the ComboBox and displaying icons in Sample source would be helpful. Thanks for taking the time to read. P.S. I've got working code which adds text to the ComboBox and its working fine but I need help adding a 32 x 32 icons beside each text.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862404/mfc-ccomboboxex-icon-update-issue?r=SearchResults&s=2|33.2070) not apply? It seems to be a duplicate question.

Comment: I was hoping for a little more code than what's shown at that link. Does anyone know whether the steps in adding icons to a CTreeCtrl will work the same as in the case of a ComboBox ?

Comment: The other answer is about the combo box, not the tree. What other code you need? Show your code first, I guess. Where does the icon come from? In what form? That’s in software terms, I.e. an icon handle, resource id, etc.

Comment: Even if no one knows the code any description or helpful links of what steps are involved in displaying icons would be appreciated. Sorry I made a typo by including the CTreeView in the OP.